Upgrading d3-sankey chart to latest version shows issue with layout method
how to resolve issue with d3-sankey chart?
I am upgrading sankey chart from 0.4.2 version to latest version, which gives error with layout method which is deprecated in latest version.
Code:
sankey
  .nodes(graph.nodes)
  .links(graph.links)
  .layout(32);

after removing layout methods error is as below

attr.js:30 Error: <g> attribute transform: Expected number, "translate(undefined,undefi…".
(anonymous) @   attr.js:30

Tried using sankey() method instead of layout but did not work.

No layout method: The layout() method is no longer part of the API. Instead, the sankey() generator computes node and link positions directly.
Declarative API: Nodes and links are passed as input objects, and the generator returns updated positions for rendering.
extent replaces chart size settings: The extent method defines the bounds of the Sankey diagram.
sankeyLinkHorizontal for link paths: A helper function generates smooth horizontal link paths.


 // Set dimensions and margins
    const width = 800;
    const height = 600;

    // Data
    const graph = {
      nodes: [
        { name: "Node A" },
        { name: "Node B" },
        { name: "Node C" },
        { name: "Node D" }
      ],
      links: [
        { source: 0, target: 1, value: 10 },
        { source: 1, target: 2, value: 15 },
        { source: 0, target: 3, value: 5 },
        { source: 3, target: 2, value: 5 }
      ]
    };

    // Create an SVG canvas
    const svg = d3.select("svg");

    // Sankey generator configuration
    const sankeyGenerator = d3.sankey()
      .nodeWidth(20)
      .nodePadding(20)
      .extent([[10, 10], [width - 10, height - 10]]);

    // Compute the Sankey layout
    const { nodes, links } = sankeyGenerator({
      nodes: graph.nodes.map(d => Object.assign({}, d)),
      links: graph.links.map(d => Object.assign({}, d))
    });

    // Define color scale
    const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

    // Render links
    svg.append("g")
      .selectAll("path")
      .data(links)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", d3.sankeyLinkHorizontal())
      .style("stroke", d => color(d.source.name))
      .style("stroke-width", d => Math.max(1, d.width));

    // Render nodes
    const node = svg.append("g")
      .selectAll("g")
      .data(nodes)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "node");

    node.append("rect")
      .attr("x", d => d.x0)
      .attr("y", d => d.y0)
      .attr("width", d => d.x1 - d.x0)
      .attr("height", d => d.y1 - d.y0)
      .style("fill", d => color(d.name))
      .style("stroke", "#000");

    node.append("text")
      .attr("x", d => d.x0 - 6)
      .attr("y", d => (d.y1 + d.y0) / 2)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(d => d.name)
      .filter(d => d.x0 < width / 2)
      .attr("x", d => d.x1 + 6)
      .attr("text-anchor", "start");
.node rect {
      stroke: #000;
    }
    .link {
      fill: none;
      stroke-opacity: 0.3;
    }
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-sankey@0.12.3/dist/d3-sankey.min.js"></script>
 <svg width="800" height="600"></svg>




This was helpful Thanks
